# How to open facebook native app on mobile from a href=""

Tags: android, html, ios, facebook

When on mobile, I want to open the facebook native app from website with `a href=""`

I tried this solution:

```
<a class="intent" target="_blank" href="fb://profile" data-scheme="fb://profile">facebook</a>
```

From this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861522/how-to-open-instagram-native-app-from-link-in-html

But it still opens up in the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will open your app (to your profile page)  -

`<h2><a href="fb://profile">FB Profile</a></h2>`

Hope it helps.

(This is tried and tested btw :) )

Update to this - your page id to load will be this -

`<h2><a href="fb://profile/655146487898613">FB Profile</a></h2>`

Comment: But it does not go to the specific page. do you know how can I go to a specific page: `fb://profile/BucharestInfo` does not work.

Comment: Ok, it works if instead of BucharestInfo I put the ID (numbers). Thanks!

Comment: Thats because you need your page ID, in your case - <h2><a href="fb://profile/655146487898613">FB Profile</a></h2>

Comment: @ashjones86 if app is not install, error can not open page. what is fallback?

Comment: @ashjones86 any idea on the fall back?

Comment: What about opening the authorization page in android? So the user can login to a give app?

Comment: @ashjones86, and how to implement the same for the youtube application?